# How to return all unique values of one column based on filtering all other variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataset with variables `group` and `X1:X1000`. For each out of columns `X1:X1000` I want to filter the rows with `0` value only and then return the unique values of `group` variable in filtered dataset. In case of single column it would be something like:

```
df %>% filter(X1 == 0) %>% select(group) %>% unique()
```

Since I want this for each column I thought that maybe `map` can be used somehow to return the list of unique values of `group` with respect to columns `X1:X1000`, but can't figure out what the call should look like.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map` to loop through the string of column names, with `filter_at`, specify the string name, to filter the rows, `select` the 'group' and get the `distinct` elements

```
library(tidyverse)
map(paste0("X", 1:1000), ~
                df %>% 
                    filter_at(vars(.x), all_vars(.==0)) %>% 
                    select(group) %>% 
                    distinct
                  )
```

---

Or instead of `filter_at`, the string can be converted to symbol (`sym`) and evaluate (`!!`) within `filter`

```
map(paste0("X", 1:1000), ~
                    df %>%
                        filter(!! (rlang::sym(.x)) ==0) %>%
                        select(group) %>%
                        distinct
              )
```

Comment: Thanks! I keep forgetting about possibility of not putting data frame as a `.x` argument of `map`, but indirectly into formula...